# Hibernate's setparameterlist not working for the selectquery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i am trying to set the parameter lTList in the sqlquery  with something like this => ['a',b','c'] but when i SOP after setting the parameter there is no change => "select .... lt in (:ltList) "
what am i doing wrong

```java
//List lTList=new ArrayList<String>();   
        
 Query selectQr = session.createSQLQuery("select id ipfs from ipfs where lt in(:lTList) and user_id='" + userId + "'");

selectQr.setParameterList("lTList", lTList);
```

There is no error but:
query constructed :   select .... lt in (:ltList)

query wanted   :   select .... lt in ('a','b','c')

Comment: This question is not understandable. Could you do more explain of your table structure? And could you give error log of console please.

Comment: Why should the query change? THe parameters are applied upon execution. Also you should never use concat to create a query like this. Use another parameter to set the userid.

Comment: query constructed : select .... lt in (:ltList)

query wanted : select .... lt in ('a','b','c')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second comment was correct,

=>Why should the query change? THe parameters are applied upon execution. Also you should never use concat to create a query like this. Use another parameter to set the userid.  - M. Deinum

The problem was that the setparameterlist was setting the parameters with quotes '', and i was already sending a list with quotes appended, thus on execution it became something like this- (''a'',''b'',''c'')

Answer (score 0):

"in(:lTList)"
"in" and "()" need a blank space

Answer (score 0):

id ipfs is one column in ipfs table or two ??

if id is a column and ipfs is an other one, you should add comma **,**
**id , ipfs**

else
you should replace the column with **'id ipfs'**

Comment: its id as ipfs(alias)

Comment: your query doesn't contains **as**